# very minimal xss prevention for loggen-in users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xss

I don't want to install any third party libraries , and users have to be in a logged in state to even get to this page.  Will this pretty much catch any malicous code that a user an enter into a comment field?

```
if (comment.CommentText.Contains("<") ||
      comment.CommentText.Contains(">") || 
      comment.CommentText.Contains("script"))
            return new EmptyResult();
```

Comment: I recently posted a comment on SO _"...go to Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Manage ..."_. I hardly think I was being malicious.

Comment: yea ... I understand that , this is just a demo version , I wouldn't use this in production.  I just wanted a quick way to ensure there were no script tags - not caring if it kind of limited text that should be ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this code won't catch 'pretty much any malicious code that a user can enter into a comment field'.

It's totally wrong. What if user want to write for example '3 < 4' in his comment? You wont accept it? Or just `script` word, it's totally safe.

Something more the script tag is not the only way to make XSS attack. (Check this [link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) if you are interested)

You should allow every character in the comments and sanitize the data when needed for the exact system where it's needed. For example the `<script>` tag (and the JavaScript inside it) is not dangerous for the database. There is other characters that are dangerous for the db and you need to escape them when inserting data in the database but the script tag should be inserted as it's totally safe.

The `XSS` prevention is made only when you show the data to the user in HTML page.

Ok, now you know when to escape your data to prevent `XSS`. There is different approaches as replacing script tags, replacing html special characters such as &, <,  and >  and so on.

From the tags of the question I can see that you are using ASP.NET MVC. The ASP.NET MVC view engine (called `Razor`) escapes the data that you write in html page by default and you don't need to take care of it unless you use the @Html.Raw helper. If you use ASPX view engine you should use `<%: myVar %>` to show the data from your variable escaped.

If you don't have these view engines on your side you probably should do some manual escaping. But then it depends where you use the data (in the html, in the attributes .. ).

If you insert the data in html the replacement of to characters bellow will be enough (but remember escape the dangerous `XSS` characters only where `XSS attack` can happen. Not when you receive inputs from user, not when inserting data in database .. but when you show it back to the user in HTML).

```
& -> &amp;
< -> &lt;
> -> &gt;
" -> &#034;
' -> &#039;
```